# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/app/Activity error when testing with JUnit in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, junit, junit4

I'm trying to test a class with JUnit and I always get this error when i try to run the test:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/app/Activity
```

This is my test class:

```
package sol.travel.trippin;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.*;
import sol.travel.trippin.LogIn;

public class LogInTest {

@Test
public void testWeakEmailAndPasswordValidation() {
    assertEquals("Vil fa true her tvi baedi eru uppfyllt", true, LogIn.weakEmailAndPasswordValidation("asdf@hi.is", 3));
    assertEquals("Vil fa false her tvi password lengd er 0", false, LogIn.weakEmailAndPasswordValidation("asdf@hi.is", 0));
    assertEquals("Vil fa false her tvi email inniheldur ekki .", false, LogIn.weakEmailAndPasswordValidation("asdf@is", 3));
    assertEquals("Vil fa false her tvi email inniheldur ekki @", false, LogIn.weakEmailAndPasswordValidation("sadfhi.is", 3));
}
```

and this is the function I'm trying to test:

```
package sol.travel.trippin;

public class LogIn extends HideKeyboard {

    public static boolean weakEmailAndPasswordValidation(String mail, int pwLength){
        if(mail.contains("@")&& mail.contains(".") && pwLength !=0 )
        {
                return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I know these functions are not good and comments regarding that are unnecessary.  All I'm trying to achieve is that I can use JUnit properly. 
So what am I missing here? Do I need to change the manifest or something else?

Comment: Maybe that's because when JUnit runs it has no reference to the android sdk? (I'm just guessing)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should extend your Test class with AndroidTestCase Look at it in Android documentation